# Angular CLI "Failed to compile". No errors, console log is empty

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

I have an Angular app, and everything was fine, till this error appeared.
I couldn´t open localhost to see console as well.

[img from cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wzuO.png)

Did someone have it? How to solve it?

Comment: What is the Pop? Can you share some more details like class and where the pop property being used? It is difficult to identify the problem from the given description.

Comment: You have somewhere pop in your code on object.

Comment: Can you post source code of that class?

Comment: do you mean pop() for array?

Comment: Can you clarify which part of code should I post, cause everything in Visual Studio is fine, no errors ?

Comment: Without complication local host is not opened , provide that error line code

Comment: Guys, I have no errors. Just inf from screenshot.

Comment: thats weird cuase everything was fine, and once .. ) I already reinstall CLI, and updated node_modules

Comment: solved .........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot, it seems that you're trying access `pop` property of an Object (`{}`) in files `bike-new.component.ts` - line 55, `order-detail.component.ts` line 54 and `order-new.component.ts` line 76.

Please check your object again, it seems that it doesn't contain any property called `pop`.

Comment: If you check the error in terminal, rows and column numbers are printed just next to the filename in round brackets.

Comment: thanks you again .. but I revised a screenshot (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wzuO.png) and didnt find where the errors appeared. No info abput line number .. sorry for lack of my skills, but can you clarify please where did you find those errors? ..

Comment: In your image, first red line: `Error in ~/bike-new.component.ts(55, 78)...`. In this, 55 is row number and 78 is column number.

Comment: HAHAHAHA!! I am coding on a laptop where a display doesnt reproduce the red color. I undestand what you are talking about now - I have an empty black space where the error should appear.. ))))))))

Comment: I have no red text on this screenshot)